# Neo4J returns empty result with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I have the following function:

```
async function getCoordinates(someId) {
  var coordinates = {longitude: 0, latitude: 0};
  var result = await neo4jsession.writeTransaction(tx =>
    tx.run(`MATCH (p:SomeEntity)
    WHERE p.some_id = "${someId}"
    RETURN p.longitude, p.latitude LIMIT 1`)
  );
  coordinates.longitude = results.records[0].get("p.longitude");
  coordinates.latitude = results.records[0].get("p.latitude");
  return coordinates;
}
```

The problem is, in the above, when I print `console.log(result)`, I see that the returned result doesn't have any `Records`. However, when I run the query:

```
MATCH (p:SomeEntity)
WHERE p.some_id = 12345
RETURN p.longitude, p.latitude LIMIT 1
```

for the same `some_id` I get the expected result. I have some other functions with queries that are working. I get this issue only with this query.

Since the query is not returning any records, `coordinates.longitude = results.records[0].get("p.longitude");` is failing with a `TypeError`.

Comment: are you  sure some_id is not "id of node" ? and print results instead of checking object properties

Comment: What do you mean? `some_id` is an attribute of a node.

Comment: to match id of node (auto generated id) we use id(node)=12345 like syntex

Comment: @shivshankar I checked this. `some_id` is not the internal id of the node. It's a custom attribute. So, this didn't work.

Comment: also make sure ${someId} is a numeric value may be you are comparing  numeric to string. remove quote if some_id is numeric

Comment: @shivshankar, yep, this was this issue...

Comment: if it helped mark answer accpeted and close question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there may two concern

> are you sure some_id is not "id of node" ?      to match id of node
>   (auto generated id) we use id(node)=12345  syntax
>
> make sure ${someId} is a numeric value may be you are comparing
>   numeric to string. remove quote if some_id is numeric